# count excel rows dynamically using python

Tags: python, excel, hash

I am writing a Python script which parses an Excel file. The aim of this script is to count for each cell value in column 1, the number of values it has in column 2.

Per example an Excel file that looks like this :

```
12    abc
12    abc
12    efg
12    efg
13    hij
13    hij
13    klm
```

My script would return:

```
For cell value 12 : 2 values "abc", 2 values "efg" and for cell value 13 : 2 values "hij" and 1 value "klm".
```

I tried using a hash in Python, here's what I'm trying to do :

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myexcelfile.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('myexcelsheet')
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
num_cells = worksheet.ncols - 1
first_col = 0
scnd_col = 1
curr_row = 1
hash = []
while curr_row < num_rows:
curr_row += 1
curr_cell = -1
print 'IN ROW', curr_row
while curr_cell < num_cells:
        curr_cell += 1
        print 'IN CELL', curr_cell
        cell0_val = int(worksheet.cell_value(curr_row,first_col))
        cell1_val = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row,scnd_col)
        print 'CELL VALUE', cell0_val, cell1_val
        hash[cell0_val][cell1_val]+=1
```

I'm certainly using that hash in a wrong way, but I really am new to Python and I can't find any good examples online that match what I really want. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're parsing an _Excel_ file and not something more like a `csv`, or some other format?  I highly doubt you'd be able to easily parse a straight up `.xls` or `.xlsx` file in Python.

Comment: He's using `xlrd`, a library to read Excel files.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like that:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myexcelfile.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('myexcelsheet')

as_list = sorted([sheet.row_values(rownum) for rownum in range(sheet.nrows)],
                 key=itemgetter(1))

for cell_value, vals in groupby(as_list, itemgetter(0)):
    letter_values = [v[1] for v in vals]
    occurrences = dict(Counter(letter_values))

    print 'For cell value {}:'.format(int(cell_value))
    print ', '.join('{} values {}'.format(str(c), v) 
                    for v, c in occurrences.items())
```

and format the output however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).
Maybe put a list inside each key.
first it's `hash = {}`

and you don't need a second loop if you only have two columns. Just do something like this

```
cell0_val = int(worksheet.cell_value(curr_row,first_col))
cell1_val = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row,scnd_col)

if cell0_val in hash:
    hash[cell0_val].append(cell1_val)
else:
    hash[cell0_val] = [cell1_val]
```

you should get something like `hash= {12: ['abc', 'abc', 'efg', 'efg'], 13: ['hij', 'hij', 'klm']}`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a double layered dictionary:

so your dictionary defined:

celldict = dict() # or celldict = {}

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myexcelfile.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('myexcelsheet')

num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
num_cells = worksheet.ncols - 1

first_col = 0
scnd_col = 1


# Read Data into double level dictionary
celldict = dict()
for curr_row in range(num_rows)  :

    #print 'IN ROW',curr_row
    cell0_val = int(worksheet.cell_value(curr_row,first_col))
    cell1_val = worksheet.cell_value(curr_row,scnd_col)

    # if this cell number isn't in my cell dict add it
    if not cell0_val in celldict :

        celldict[cell0_val] = dict()

    # if the entry isn't in the second level dictionary then add it, with count 1

    if not cell1_val in celldict[cell0_val] :
        celldict[cell0_val][cell1_val] = 1

    # Otherwise increase the count
    else :
        celldict[cell0_val][cell1_val] += 1

# Outputs Dictionary hierachy
print   celldict
# Outputs it more pretiliy
for cellval in celldict :
    print "For cell value ", cellval  ,":"
    for cellval2 in celldict[cellval] :
        print cellval2," values", celldict[cellval][cellval2]
```